# How do I resolve mach-o architecture errors when using capybara-webkit and QT

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, webkit, capybara, qtwebkit

I am using capybara-webkit on OS X Lion.  I used brew to install QT, which seems to have installed successfully along with the capybara-webkit gem.  I'm getting the following errors and am not entirely sure how to resolve them.

I do some research online, but it looks like my architectures match up as running file on the plugin shows i386.  Any input?

```
2011-09-19 19:58:26.289 webkit_server[9927:107] Error loading /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/SharePointBrowserPlugin.plugin/Contents/MacOS/SharePointBrowserPlugin:  dlopen(/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/SharePointBrowserPlugin.plugin/Contents/MacOS/SharePointBrowserPlugin, 262): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/SharePointBrowserPlugin.plugin/Contents/MacOS/SharePointBrowserPlugin: mach-o, but wrong architecture
2011-09-19 19:58:26.291 webkit_server[9927:107] Error loading /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/QuickTime Plugin.plugin/Contents/MacOS/QuickTime Plugin:  dlopen(/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/QuickTime Plugin.plugin/Contents/MacOS/QuickTime Plugin, 265): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/QuickTime Plugin.plugin/Contents/MacOS/QuickTime Plugin: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently had a similar issue where rails was throwing the "but wrong architecture no suitable image found" error when starting rails console or the rails server.

Running `file` on the associatd .dylib files, and the gem, generally returned either an applicable x86_64 version, or a universal which included it.  Eventually, I traced it back to the actual version of Ruby I was running.  The /usr/bin/ruby executable itself was only i386 compatible.  This was really a shocker, as I assumed the new xcode and osx 10.7 would have brought me a 64 bit ruby.

Using RVM, I installed another instance of ruby (again 1.8.7).  Doing this required that I install a new instance of readline (for which I used homebrew, : `brew install readline`) and installed the rvm with `rvm install 1.8.7 --with-readline-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/readline/6.2.1/`.

After doing this, and switching to use my new ruby instance (`rvm use 1.8.7`), all my gems were gone (the RVM install somehow changed my default gem_path.)  `gem install rake`, followed by `gem install bundler`, and then `bundle install` got me up and running.

Long story short, make sure your ruby executable matches the instruction-set version that your ruby/rails packages are were built in.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in the next link

https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/issues/157